# How much can MIPS stack hold?

Tags: mips, mips32

Using [QtSpim MIPS Simulator](http://spimsimulator.sourceforge.net/), how much can the stack `$sp` hold? The initial value `$sp` is `2147481160`. I know that there is an offset of 4 for each word to be stored in the stack. Would I just divide `2147481160` by 4 to get the limit of words?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, the "bottom" of the user data space is 0x10000000.  However, global data goes at this address, so the actual bottom of the stack would be at the end of this data (which would depend on the specific program).  For what it's worth, in MARS (another MIPS simulator), the bottom of the stack is set at 0x10040000.  Also, remember, this value only applies if you haven't put any data on the heap.

Comment: To see a complete example memory map, launch [MARS] (http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/), then go to Settings -> Memory Configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Each word is `4 bytes = 32 bits`. Thus, the stack can hold `(2147481160/4) = 536870290`, `536870290 * 32 bits of data`.

Comment: You'd have to discount the space used by the code and data sections.